# Can't play .amr file in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, audio-recording, amr, soundeffect

I use AudioVideoCaptureDevice to record the voice and save it to isolated storage with amr format

```
dev = await AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenForAudioOnlyAsync();
dev.AudioEncodingFormat = CameraCaptureAudioFormat.Amr;
```

I can play it by windows media player. But I can't play it with SoundEffect in WP8.

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream sourceFile = ISF.OpenFile("\\data\\test.amr", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
   byte[] b = new byte[sourceFile.Length];
   sourceFile.Read(b, 0, b.Length);
   SoundEffect sound = new SoundEffect(b, microphone.SampleRate, AudioChannels.Mono);
   soundInstance = sound.CreateInstance();
   soundInstance.Play();
}
```

Please help me to know why and help me to solve this problem. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not working because souneffect only accepts .wav file...|
it does not support any other format except that ...
so change your file format it should work fine...