# How to play amr file in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: audio, windows-phone-8, playback, amr, soundeffect

From what I read, [WP8 does support amr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462087%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

However, I don't know how to play it.

1. When using `SoundEffect`, I can't hear anything, maybe it's because `SoundEffect` supports `wav` only. Someone already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276626/cant-play-amr-file-in-wp8).
2. I don't want to use `BackgroundAudioPlayer` or `MediaPlayerLauncher`, as they are overkill

Is there any workaround to play `amr` with `SoundEffect`, or is there a better API to play it ?

**P/S:** this amr file is record using WP8 API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play them using a MediaElement.  Just add a MediaElement to your xaml file.  Then set the source to your opened file.  Something like:

```
using(IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = appStorage.OpenFile(mFilename, FileMode.Open))
{
     mMediaPlayer.SetSource(stream);
}
```

Then when you want to play the audio you call:

```
mMediaPlayer.Play();
```